# PHP file not found while running in docker on Windows

Tags: php, windows, docker, typo3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

At work I work on a laptop with Windows 10 Pro + Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) + Docker. The issue I'm facing is as follows.

I'm developing a plugin for TYPO3 CMS. I have a `docker-compose` script that sets up the whole environment for me. I use Nginx, PHP 7.2 FPM and MySQL 5.6. But after installing TYPO3 9LTS and going to its backend I get tons of PHP errors, such as

`PHP Warning: include('./vendor/autoload.php'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

But the file is physically there! This problem is totally random. Sometimes it will load this file but then it dies at wanting to include another file.

File permissions seems to be fine. I tried this with 2 different `docker-compose` scripts and both have the same issue. However, when I tried them on native Linux they work flawlessly.

I should mention that I already a have sort of working TYPO3 installation on WSL and docker for version 7 of the CMS. From time to time I also get the `No such file or directory` error but after a refresh in the browser it's fine. Docker set up is similar, though (the webserver image is only different - Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.2 vs Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0) but it doesn't work at all for TYPO3 version 9.

I use the following docker composer boilerplates:

1. https://phpdocker.io/generator - PHP 7.2, nginx and MySQL (everything else is excluded)
2. https://github.com/webdevops/TYPO3-docker-boilerplate - Pretty much similar as the above. In the `Dockerfile.development` I changed the image to pull from `webdevops/php-nginx-dev:ubuntu-18.04`

I haven't tried to run it on Apache + mod_php yet but I might. It's just that I'm used to nginx so I prefer to use it over Apache.

Comment: I just tried running it on Apache but that didn't change anything. Looks more like filesystem issue of docker on Windows.